# How long might a couple have 'courted' and been engaged in mid-nineteenth century Wales?

Tags: 19th-century, wales, marriage-practices

What might the 'courting' and engagement period have been for a young couple in mid-nineteenth century Merthyr Tydfil. Their ages were both recorded as 21 at their marriage in the Register Office (when her step-father was present) but she was closer to 18.  There's no evidence either way as to whether she was pregnant at the time. The couple were solidly working-class (coal miner and the daughter of a coal-miner).

Obviously, there can't be a definitive answer, only a range of possibilities, but I'm interested in whether a couple that married in early May 1862 in Merthyr Tydfil could have known each other (and so both been living in or around Merthyr Tydfil) in April 1861; or whether I should also be looking further afield for the husband in 1861.  (The wife was living in the Merthyr Tydfil area in the 1861 census).

Note: Rebecca Probert *Marriage Law for Genealogists* is silent on the subject, and I can't find anything relevant in Wrigley and Schofield *The Population History of England 1541-1871*

Comment: Good question, but it makes me think of a related question about how far afield one should look (courting distance rather than length of courtship).

Comment: @JanMurphy True, although given the nature of MT at this time (a population magnet), I suspect they both lived in the MT area during their courtship.